# サスペンド＆レジュームを行うとアプリクラッシュが発生する

Tags: android, unity3d

Unity4.5.4にてUnityで作成したアプリがクラッシュしてしまう現状が発生しております。

手順としては下記となります。

1. Unity側からAndroidの自作したプラグインを呼び出す
2. プラグイン側でシステムダイアログを表示する
3. ダイアログを閉じる
4. Unityの処理へ戻る際に、”サスペンド&レジューム”を行う
5. 「問題が発生したため”アプリ名”を終了します。」と表示されアプリクラッシュが発生する。

何か原因と考えられる事は御座いますでしょうか？ 
推測として復帰時に、Activityのプロセスが削除され、削除されたプロセス内の情報にアクセスし
クラッシュしているのではと考えております。

下記はクラッシュ時のログとなります。

```
A/libc(15917): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15932 (UnityMain) 
E/qcomsensorshal(749): halprocessreportind: Bad item quality: 11 
I/DEBUG(180): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGVMAPERR), fault addr 00000000 
I/AudioFlinger(186): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4098) from active list on thread 0xb5e98008 
W/AudioTrack(15917): releaseBuffer() track 0x83e2bdd0 name=s:186;n:2;f:-1 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting 
W/ActivityManager(749): Force finishing activity {BundleId}/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity 
W/InputDispatcher(749): channel '42b2aec8 {BundleId}/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x9 
E/InputDispatcher(749): channel '42b2aec8 {BundleId}/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 
I/WindowState(749): WIN DEATH: Window{42b2aec8 u0 {BundleId}/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity} 
W/InputDispatcher(749): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42b2aec8 {BundleId}/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' 
I/ActivityManager(749): Process {BundleId} (pid 15917) has died. 
I/WindowState(749): WIN DEATH: Window{42dc6310 u0 SurfaceView} 
D/Zygote(183): Process 15917 terminated by signal (11) 
I/ActivityManager(749): Config changes=480 {1.0 440mcc?mnc jaJP ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 480dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.183} 
I/InputReader(749): Reconfiguring input devices. changes=0x00000004 
I/InputReader(749): Device reconfigured: id=4, name='touchdev', size 1080x1920, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0 
D/PhoneStatusBar(854): mSettingsPanelGravity = 55 
E/qcomsensorshal(749): halprocessreportind: Bad item quality: 11 
D/dalvikvm(854): GCCONCURRENT freed 7663K, 17% free 51977K/62236K, paused 3ms+16ms, total 62ms 
I/WindowManager(749): Screen frozen for +382ms due to Window{42c58bf8 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper} 
E/qcomsensorshal(749): halprocessreportind: Bad item quality: 11 
D/dalvikvm(749): GCEXPLICIT freed 2014K, 21% free 31940K/40392K, paused 13ms+6ms, total 108ms 
E/qcomsensorshal(749): halprocessreport_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```